# high availabilty port forwarding in mswindows

Tags: windows, port-forwarding, tcpip

I need port forwarding for a mswindows host, but I need something which can handle more than one target with fail over. There are no end of tools to do this on Linux/Unix (haproxy, balance, pound....). I believe its possible to implement port forwarding using netsh add v4tov4 however this only allows for a single target?

Comment: You are not attempting to set up some advanced routing mumbo-jumbo with Windows, are you? Grandma said not to even think of it. I believe you would have to use a dedicated load balancer for what you're asking. Forefront TMG used to have load balancing capabilities as part of its feature set AFAIR, but it is discontinued.

Comment: Why can't you use haproxy or similar packages BTW?

Comment: HAProxy is available on MSWindows? This is news to me - I've only seen Linux/Unix versions (including HAPEE). Can you provide a URL?

Comment: reportedly, haproxy does *compile* with Cygwin, although I doubt you would want to put that into production. But why can't you run a Linux (virtual) machine for that purpose?

Comment: I've some software that only runs on mswindows, but want fault tolerance where the client is running. The only option I've found so far is nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Windows servers can be configured with Network Load Balancing. All server listen on a VIP on the same port or range of ports. It isn't fully smart enough to remove down servers from the pool, it's just a round-robin, but it's a start.

Comment: Yes, aware of this. And PAINFULLY aware how (un) reliable floating/shared IP addresses are as an architecture for implementing failover, and Microsoft's implementation in particular - hence the reason for trying to move the management of failover to the client.

Comment: I have a faint recollection of doing a POC based on MS Application and Request Routing, which is an IIS reverse proxy/rewrite addon that can handle health checking, failover and quite a number of other common features (but only for web traffic of course..). It was a nice encounter, but had the interesting shortcoming of the ARR proxy node not being fault tolerant in itself, so to make the reverse-proxy layer redundant one had to either NLB multiple ARR nodes or put another load balancer in front...

Comment: Yeah, at some point you've got to have a VIP. End of story

Comment: I don't want this to get into a discussion about every possible high availability architecture and the relative benefits of them - but a VIP is *not* the only way to solve the problem and introduces additional complications.